# Making OAuth2 Request to Discord with Authorization code to get Access Token | C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, discord

I am working on a project that connects to Discord's OAuth API via C# ASP.NET MVC. I am having trouble formatting my post request so that it doesn't return an HTTP error 400 (bad request). I have found plenty of examples for Python or JS but none for C# or ASP.NET. I was wondering if anyone could provide an example of a POST request to Discords API (https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token) with an Auth code to get the access token.